# Why is mobile menu not working?

Tags: mobile

## Background

I have a website with a mobile hamburger-style menu, which is not working. The menu button is displaying correctly, but nothing happens when it is clicked/touched.

## Code

**Backend PHP:**

```
<!-- Mobile Links -->
                    <a href="#" id="mobile-menu-icon" class="mobile-menu-icon show-for-custom-down" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Mobile Menu', 'punjaban' ); ?>"><span class="lines"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="mobile-search-icon" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Search', 'punjaban' ); ?>">
                    </a>

                    <!-- Mobile Menu -->
                    <?php 
register_nav_menus( array(
    'mobile-primary-menu' => 'Mobile Navigation Menu',
    ) );
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'mobile-primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

**Final HTML:**

```
<!-- Mobile Links -->
                    <a href="#" id="mobile-menu-icon" class="mobile-menu-icon show-for-custom-down" title="Mobile Menu"><span class="lines"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="mobile-search-icon" title="Search">
                    </a>

                    <!-- Mobile Menu -->
                    <div class="mobile-primary-menu"><ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-21" class="search-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-21"><a rel="nofollow" href="#">Search</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-407" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-407"><a rel="nofollow" href="/shop">SHOP</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-239"><a rel="nofollow" href="/recipes">RECIPES</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a rel="nofollow" href="/stockist">STOCKISTS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-598" class="fourth-child menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-598"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.punjaban.co.uk/our-story/">OUR STORY</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19"><a rel="nofollow" href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.punjaban.co.uk/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Can anybody suggest what might be going wrong please?

Comment: The code that you have linked doesn't have anything to do with the menu opening or closing. The open/close change is either Javascript (likely), or CSS (unlikely but possible). Use the inspector to see if the button is getting it's click event listeners and see if you can trace the problem backwards.

Comment: Thanks Andy, looking it with the debugger it doesn;t seem to be firing any javascript. I searched and found the following but it is never called:  `//Mobile Menu Icon Toggle
 jQuery("#mobile-menu-icon").click(function(){
  jQuery(".mobile-primary-menu").stop().fadeToggle("fast");
  jQuery("body").toggleClass("no-scroll");
  return false;
 });`

Comment: `#mobile-menu-icon` is jQuery's way of attaching a click event listener to `<a href="#" id="mobile-menu-icon" class="mobile-menu-icon show-for-custom-down" title="Mobile Menu"><span class="lines"></span></a>`. Should be working. On Firefox/Chrome inspectors, they will show an icon indicating an element has an event listener. Is that showing on the actual button element?

Comment: No, there is no Event Listener displaying on the button element. Can I add one to the code above?

Comment: The jQuery code you linked does that. Sometimes is causing it not to be run. I'd have to actually look at the code to figure it out, I'm sorry. (If you'd like to email me a link, I could take a look tonight if no one else has an answer here. Not sure if the site is confidential or something.)

Comment: OK, thanks Andy, sorry I'm quite out of my depth here!  The website is www.punjaban.co.uk. I would be very appreciative if you could take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118845/discussion-between-helen-and-andym).